# How to get Full URL in a jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to get the current page full URL in jsp page?

I have tried different ways:

`request.getRequestURL` and

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

and some other ways but its not returning the exact full URL as shown in the URL Address field. Is there anything like `window.location.href` in jsp page like it works in Javascript which exactly return the whole URL?

Any suggestions here please?

Answer (score 0):

```
The String url = request. GetRequestURI ();

StringBuffer url_buffer = request. GetRequestURL ();
```

It both methods can only get the request url does not contain parameters, the difference is as follows:

1 .the former returns relative path, the latter returns the full path

2 .which returns a string, who returned to stringbuffer

Get complete request url can through the following method getQueryString () get a url string at the back of the parameters, and the former is combined with the parameters of the request path

```
String the queryString = request. GetQueryString ();
Ring fullPath = url + the queryString. / / or url_buffer. ToString () + the queryString.
```